# Where is the following incident found?

Tags: scripture, rishi, reference-request, devatas

There is a story roughly as follows:

A sage (probably Angiras, though I don't remember for certain) was preaching jnan to his ancestors by addressing them as his children. Then, his ancestors complained to devas, who replied that "you are indeed like children in knowledge"

Where is this passage found?

Comment: It will help if you clrify in your question, where you heard it, or read it.

Comment: Sir, it was in a website regarding types of Gurus I think ...I dont remember properly